# How can I center this form?

Tags: html, css

I made a login form that's perfectly horizontally centered for wide screens. Somehow, it's not the case with small screens, even though I used the viewport tag and `margin: 0 auto;`. What's wrong and how can I center it correctly?

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}

fieldset {
  border: 1px groove black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

form {
  font-family: Segoe UI;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 15%;
  width: 27.5%;
}

input {
  border: 1px rgb(175, 175, 175) solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin-top: 2.5%;
  padding: 1% 0% 1% 0%;
}

legend {
  font-size: 150%;
}

button {
  background-color: rgb(0, 117, 255);
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.15s ease-out;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0, 83, 255);
  transition: background-color 0.15s ease-in;
}

button#submit {
  font-size: 100%;
  margin-top: 7%;
  padding: 2.5% 10% 2.5% 10%;
}

button#signup {
  font-size: 100%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  padding: 0.6% 2.5% 0.6% 2.5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<html>

<head>
  <title>Login</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css">
</head>

<body>
  <form action="background_processing/login_process.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Login</legend>
      <p>
        <label for="username">Username</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="password">Password</label><br>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
      </p>
      <p>
        <button type="submit" id="submit">Log in</button>
      </p>
    </fieldset>
  </form><br>
  <button id="signup" onclick="window.open('https://google.com/','_self');">Sign up</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Here's my code: https://jsfiddle.net/gabwvf68

Comment: Looks centered to me? The horizontal scrollbar results from you not having changed to the `border-box` box-model.

Comment: If it's vertical centering you're gonna have to take a look at flex-box

Comment: @connexo I think he means vertical centering

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to vertically center a div for all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers)

Comment: OK, it looks like your inputs are pushing up the size of the fieldset to overflow the form.   Your form is centred, but the fieldset is extending to the right.  Put a `display:none` property on your inputs and it no longer happens.

Comment: So, you need to do something about the input size to fix it.

Comment: @connexo - the form horizonally decentres as you shrink the containing window (at least it does on Chrome and Firefox anyway)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your problem area:

```
    fieldset {
      border: 1px groove black;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }

    form {
      font-family: Segoe UI;
      margin: 0 auto;
      margin-top: 15%;
      width: 27.5%;
    }
```

We can fix it simply by doing:

```
    fieldset {
      border: 1px groove black;
      border-radius: 5px;
      width: 27.5%;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    form {
      font-family: Segoe UI;
      margin-top: 15%;
    }
```

Move the width and `margin: 0 auto;` to the fieldset.

`margin 0 auto;` should always go on the block you are trying to center not the parent block.

Comment: Good catch - you got there before me.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks. What I wanted to center though, was indeed the form and not the fieldset but another comment made me realize that the fieldset was overflowing due to the inputs and buttons having a fixed width, which caused the offset for smaller screens.

Answer (score 1):

You form has the width in percent is smaller that the `fieldset` area. Hence when you resize the window to smaller size it moves right to get the remaining wind of the window. Try giving fix width or the width as much as `fieldset` element width.

Like below I gave `width:55%` and it works fine for all window size. If you want the box width as given in the example, try giving it `width:300px`

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}

fieldset {
  border: 1px groove black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

form {
  font-family: Segoe UI;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 15%;
  width: 55%;
}

input {
  border: 1px rgb(175, 175, 175) solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin-top: 2.5%;
  padding: 1% 0% 1% 0%;
}

legend {
  font-size: 150%;
}

button {
  background-color: rgb(0, 117, 255);
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.15s ease-out;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0, 83, 255);
  transition: background-color 0.15s ease-in;
}

button#submit {
  font-size: 100%;
  margin-top: 7%;
  padding: 2.5% 10% 2.5% 10%;
}

button#signup {
  font-size: 100%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  padding: 0.6% 2.5% 0.6% 2.5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<html>

<head>
  <title>Login</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css">
</head>

<body>
  <form action="background_processing/login_process.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Login</legend>
      <p>
        <label for="username">Username</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="password">Password</label><br>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
      </p>
      <p>
        <button type="submit" id="submit">Log in</button>
      </p>
    </fieldset>
  </form><br>
  <button id="signup" onclick="window.open('https://google.com/','_self');">Sign up</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I just forgot to give a relative size to the buttons and inputs instead of the default fixed one.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue lies with the use of the `<fieldset>` tag which even though the parent form is correctly sized and centred the `fieldset` child does not display to this size.

One way around this if you do not require the `fieldset` tag is to use a `div` with the class `fieldset`.

You should probably also include a `width: 100%` attribute to the input fields so that they remain within the input form.

**Example**

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}

.fieldset {
  border: 1px groove black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

form {
  font-family: Segoe UI;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 15%;
  width: 27.5%;
}

input {
  border: 1px rgb(175, 175, 175) solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 2.5%;
  padding: 1% 0% 1% 0%;
}

legend {
  font-size: 150%;
}

button {
  background-color: rgb(0, 117, 255);
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.15s ease-out;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0, 83, 255);
  transition: background-color 0.15s ease-in;
}

button#submit {
  font-size: 100%;
  margin-top: 7%;
  padding: 2.5% 10% 2.5% 10%;
}

button#signup {
  font-size: 100%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  padding: 0.6% 2.5% 0.6% 2.5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<html>

<head>
  <title>Login</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css">
</head>

<body>
  <form action="background_processing/login_process.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <div class="fieldset">
      <legend>Login</legend>
      <p>
        <label for="username">Username</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="password">Password</label><br>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
      </p>
      <p>
        <button type="submit" id="submit">Log in</button>
      </p>
    </div>
  </form><br>
  <button id="signup" onclick="window.open('https://google.com/','_self');">Sign up</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

your form is actually centered, but in small screen, form content (fieldset, input etc.) kind of overflows your form area. you can visualize this by temporarily adding `background-color` to the form. In order to fix this, try setting larger width of form for smaller screen. Also, use `px` value for `width` instead of `%`, if possible